# call a function in an other iframe on a different layer

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to call a function from an other frame. But when I use "document.getElementById(frame_id))" it isn't found.

I checked what the innerHTML output of the document was and the iframe i need to target is 1 layer up inside another iframe.

In the main iframe i use:
document.getElementById('player')) but it retuns: null

I need to get to the "player" iframe in the "menu" iframe..

here is the code in the "main" iframes head:

```
function callPlayer(frame_id, func, args){
    if(!frame_id) return;
    if(frame_id.id) frame_id = frame_id.id;
    else if(typeof jQuery != "undefined" && frame_id instanceof jQuery && frame_id.length) frame_id = frame_id.get(0).id;
    if(!document.getElementById(frame_id)) return;
    args = args || [];

    /*Searches the document for the IFRAME with id=frame_id*/
    var all_iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for(var i=0, len=all_iframes.length; i<len; i++){
        if(all_iframes[i].id == frame_id || all_iframes[i].parentNode.id == frame_id){
           /*The index of the IFRAME element equals the index of the iframe in
             the frames object (<frame> . */
           window.frames[i].postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                "event": "command",
                "func": func,
                "args": args,
                "id": frame_id
            }), "*");
        }
    }
}

function switchState()
{
    callPlayer('player', 'stopVideo');
}
```

Hope someone understands my description..

[image: the HTML in Firebug]

Comment: Wait, why is there an html tag in the iframe?

Comment: the website is based on the KusabaX 0.9.3 Framework. It's the way the site is built up and I will not be able to change that..

Comment: @JeffreySweeney because the iframe contains a valid HTML document so the first child of the iframe should always be HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("player").contentWindow
```

from the "main" iframe to target the window object of the "player" iframe, and call its functions there.

For example:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.player_func();
```

Comment: window.parent.document.getElementById("player").contentWindow returns null

Comment: Right, I missed that the player iframe is inside the menu iframe. So you'd have to go through that: window.parent.document.getElementById("menu").contentWindow.document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.player_func();

Comment: Nine years later your code saved the day for me, thanks, Joel!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parent` object to address the container in which your `main` iframe resides.

Comment: It looks like Hagbart is using `postMessage` to message a youtube page, which would suggest that the page is on a different domain. Therefore, `parent` wouldn't work.

Comment: I am using the javascript youtube API to embed the video. The reason is i want to have a button in the "main" iframe to toggle the player to start and stop. It's all in the same domain.